# owlcarousel loop, 1st image in new loop appears with a delay

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm using http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ on my wordpress site.

Slide consists of image and text.

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   items:3,
loop:true,
margin:10,
autoplay:true,
autoplaySpeed:1000,
autoplayHoverPause:true
```

})

Everything is ok, but when the new look starts, 1st image appears with a small delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, if u are using chrome it might be the:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

set on **".owl-carousel .owl-item "** **in owl.carousel.css**

When i commented that out it the delays stoped.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it overwriting owl-hidden class and setting opacity to 1, like that:

```
.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 1;
}
```